# How to change language bar background color based on language selected?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, language-bar

Is there a way to change the background color of the language bar icon in the taskbar on windows (windows 10)?

I found something here: [https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/133396-language-bar-color.html#:~:text=%236-,Is%20it%20the%20red%20box%20with%20black%20text%20EN%20%3F%20If%20so%20yes%20it%20can%20be%20changed%20in%20the%20.msstyle%20of%20the%20theme.,-Attached%20Thumbnails](https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/133396-language-bar-color.html#:%7E:text=%236-,Is%20it%20the%20red%20box%20with%20black%20text%20EN%20%3F%20If%20so%20yes%20it%20can%20be%20changed%20in%20the%20.msstyle%20of%20the%20theme.,-Attached%20Thumbnails)

I'm wondering if I can change it based on what language is selected. It would be quite useful because I switch between multiple languages frequently and a color would be a great indicator.

The language bar icon is circled in red in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Any solution is welcome.

Comment: Also, the reason the icon is colored in the picture I included, is because it was highlighted from mouse hovering over it which the snapshot didn't include